# loop over company names ssis 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have tables from navision which names are

```
 dbo.[CompanyName$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]
```

I have 30 companies . I am looking to loop over companies 
I follow this solution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a13d39ab-968b-41f2-bf85-cb46db763d4e/variable-to-dynamically-change-tablename-for-data-flow-task

But how can I use it in the data flow task ? how can I change table names dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I can see from your other post that you have attempted things rather than just asking how to do something, so I will give you a hand.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

[image: Example_Loop_Container]

Here is an example of the SSIS package.

For starters you will need 3 variables:

[image: Variables]

Two string variables i've called them CompanyName and SQLStatement and an Object Variable which i've called CompanyList.

We first of all need to populate the CompanyList, we do so in the Execute SQL Task.

[image: Execute_SQL_Task]

We need to set the Result Set to be "Full Result Set", then in the SQL Statement you need to add your way of getting the full company names, for instance "Select distinct Name from dbo.company", here we then store these results in the Object variable:

[image: Result_Set]

This will now store all the results into the Object Variable.

We now need to setup our SQLStatement Variable. The variable is just a string variable however what we need to do it set it to "EvaluateAsExpression" - "True":

[image: EvaluateAsExpression]

In the expression we need to enter the following:

```
"Select * from dbo.[" +  @[User::CompanyName] + "$Cust_ Ledger Entry].[Customer No_]"
```

Now this is setup we can get on with the ForeachLoop.

[image: ForEachLoop]

Set the ForEachLoop as above, where we want to evaluate "Rows in first table" against the "CompanyList" object variable.

The next step is to map that to our final variable "CompanyName" which will be used in out SQL Expression:

[image: VariableMapping]

In the ForEachLoop go to the VariableMapping tab and enter Select the "CompanyName" variable with Index 0, this will change the "CompanyName" variable each time the loop runs, effectively changing the SQL Statement Variable allowing us to loop through each of the companies.

The final step is to go into the DFT and setup the OLEDB Source:

[image: OLEDB Source]

For the OLEDB Source we need to select "SQL command from variable", here we then select the "SQLStatement" variable.

You can then carry on your DFT as you wish.